# Check if there's exactly one match in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

The challenge is to **iterate over the vector only once** and return the value within the range of the zero. However, if there are no matches or more than 1 match, deliver an error. The vector is **unsorted** and has no guarantee on it's size or the range of data.
More technically, the number of data accesses into the vector can't exceed `N + 1` (access to iterators doesn't count)

I did this with a simple loop with 2 nested checks, and was wondering if there was a stdlib based or a better algorithmic solution that I'm not able to find.

Maybe ranges can help, but I'm limited to c++17 here, though the only c++17 feature I'm using is `std::optional` for error handling.

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <vector>

std::optional<int> get_unambiguous(const std::vector<int> &data,
                                    const int range,
                                    const int zero = 0)
{
    std::optional<int> found;
    for (const auto& item: data)
    {
        if (std::abs(item - zero) < range) {
            if (found) {
                return {};
            }
            found = item;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library find functions return the `.end()` iterator for the container if they fail to find anything. We could follow the same convention, instead of using `std::optional`.

Rather than nesting the checks, we could split it into two separate loops, and use  `std::find_if` from the `<algorithm>` header, something like this:

```
auto const is_in_range = [&] (int item) { return std::abs(item - zero) < range; };

auto const first = std::find_if(data.begin(), data.end(), is_in_range);

if (first == data.end())
    return data.end(); // found nothing

auto const second = std::find_if(std::next(first), data.end(), is_in_range);

if (second != data.end())
    return data.end(); // found a second entry

return first;
```

Comment: Ah yes! This is basically what I'm doing. Find twice. So simple. Thanks :)

Comment: And I totally missed the `container.end` for error. This makes it even more generic. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many subtle and not so subtle design-considerations for you:

1. Just getting an optional value is restrictive, as you cannot modify it.
2. Just getting an optional value is moderately surprising, as nearly all other relevant APIs return an iterator, which can be the end-iterator to indicate failure.
3. Just adding basic templating would allow use of any kind of range, not just `std::vector<int>`.
   Alternatively, if you stay with a contiguous sequence of `int`s, [use `span<const int>` from the GSL or C++20](//stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one).
4. [Signed integer overflow is Undefined Behavior](//stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one). So yes, simply subtracting there is a bug, as we don't know anything about the values.
5. A better name for `range` would be `delta`, and for `zero` consider `center`.
6. Unless the type of `delta` is bigger than the value_type, or unsigned, you cannot ask to match all.
7. Considering all the problems, why not use min and max in the interface instead?
8. Consider using the standard algorithms instead of rolling your own. They won't be any less efficient.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
auto get_only_match(T const& data, T::value_type delta, T::value_type mid = T::value_type()) {
    if (delta <= 0) return data.end();
    using limits = std::numeric_limits<T::value_type>;
    auto min = limits::min() + delta > mid ? limits::min() : mid - delta;
    auto max = limits::max() - delta < mid ? limits::max() : mid + delta;
    auto pred = [&](auto item) { return min < item && item < max; };
    auto f = [&](auto pos) { return std::find_if(pos, data.end(), pred); };
    if (auto match = f(data.begin()); match != data.end())
        if (f(std::next(match)) == data.end())
            return match;
    return data.end();
}
```

Or using the simpler and more flexible description for integer-ranges:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
auto get_only_match(T const& data, T::value_type min, T::value_type max) {
    auto pred = [&](auto item) { return min <= item && item <= max; };
    auto f = [&](auto pos) { return std::find_if(pos, data.end(), pred); };
    if (auto match = f(data.begin()); match != data.end())
        if (f(std::next(match)) == data.end())
            return match;
    return data.end();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're just checking for two values in a range, use a lambda and search linearly through the vector. To speed things up, you can break once you find a second value in that range. Here's how I did it:

```cpp
struct Match
{
    bool has_match;
    int value;
};

Match has_one_match(const std::vector<int>& data, int lower, int upper)
{
    if (upper < lower)
    {
        return { false, 0 };
    }

    unsigned times_found = 0;
    const auto is_in_range = [&lower, &upper](int input)
    {
        return input >= lower && input <= upper;
    };

    Match ret_match{ false, 0 };
    for (const auto& num : data)
    {
        if (is_in_range(num))
        {
            if (++times_found == 2)
            { // 2 values found, condition violated; break
                break;
            }

            ret_match.value = num;
        }
    }

    if (times_found == 1)
    {
        ret_match.has_match = true;
    }

    return ret_match;
}
```

From there, to avoid using `std::optional`, just check if `Match::has_match` is true before preforming anything with the value.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange, for a c++17 solution one would rather like to see algorithms used over for loops, `find_if` for example. There isn't really a reason to reimplement `std::optional`. Although your implementation could be improved by pre-initializing `has_match{false}` in the declaration. This way a default constructed `Match` instance would be valid

Comment: @HaraldScheirich Thank you for the feedback! My goal was more to give a method that did not rely on the STL.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson this offers no improvements from an algorithm perspective. It's true it doesn't have STL except the std::vector, but I really hoped for a clever algorithm or something in STL which I missed (like the accepted answer)